# Frequency power vs signal power

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft, frequency, modulation

I have to analyse a signal which has been modulated with a QPSK using matlab and I can't seem to get things right.

What I have: a complex signal sampled at a known frequency.

What I want: the power ratio of a certain frequency. So if the signal is of the form `a*cos(wt)+a*cos(2wt)` then I should get `0.5 for w` and `0.5 for 2w`.

I don't know where is the problem with my code but I get a frequency power higher than the signal power as you can see it in the graph bellow (in `blue: signalPower`, in `red: Fm`).

[image: Signal power vs Frequency Power]

And here is my code:

```
% Nsym : Number of symbol used for the detection
% Ns : Number ofsamples per symbol
% IQrx : Complex signal to analyse
% Fmod : Modulation frequency

Nt = Nsym*Ns;
signalPower = zeros(1, length(IQrx));
Fp = zeros(1, length(IQrx));
Fm = zeros(1, length(IQrx));
for ii = 1:length(IQrx)
    for jj = 0:Nt-1
        if ii-jj > 0 && ii-jj <= length(IQrx)
            signalPower(ii) = signalPower(ii) + ...
                abs(IQrx(ii-jj))^2;
            Fp(ii) = Fp(ii) + ...
                IQrx(ii-jj) * ...
                exp(1i*2*pi*Fmod*(ii-jj)/obj.Fs);
            Fm(ii) = Fm(ii) + ...
                IQrx(ii-jj) * ...
                exp(-1i*2*pi*Fmod*(ii-jj)/obj.Fs);
        end
    end
    Fp(ii) = abs(Fp(ii))^2;
    Fm(ii) = abs(Fm(ii))^2;
end
```

Edit: As requested in the comments the formulas that I use are:
Consider that i goes in the time window of interest.

> signalPower = sum ( signal(i)^2 )
>
> Fp = abs( sum( signal * exp(1i*2*pi*Fmod*(i)/obj.Fs) ) )^2
>
> Fp = abs( sum( signal * exp(-1i*2*pi*Fmod*(i)/obj.Fs) ) )^2

Comment: Looks like you're convolving your signal with the magnitude squared of the received signal and also convolving the received signal with a dirac delta in the time domain, and taking the magnitude squared each loop.  Can you reference what formula you are using to determine spectral power?

Comment: @macduff I referenced the formulas as you suggested!

Comment: This really belongs on dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: @BjornRoche I didn't know it existed. I'll post it there then. Should I delete this thread too?

Comment: Since you have an answer, I wouldn't do anything. But in the future, for similar questions, you know what to do :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me that

```
signalPower(ii) = signalPower(ii) + abs(IQrx(ii-jj))^2;
```

Should be something more like:

```
signalPower(ii) = signalPower(ii) + abs(IQrx(ii-jj));
```

You might want to try something a bit simpler for the signal power like:

pwt=x'*x; % Power in time domain

where `x` is your windowed time series value. (inspiration from [this link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/34658)).